# R-language recursive function

Tags: r, recursion

When I run this function

```
log_gamma_recursive <- function(n) 
{
  if (n == 1)    
    return (1)

  y = (n-1)* log_gamma_recursive(n-1) 

  log(y)
}
```

I get

> [1] NaN
>   Warning message:
>   In log(y) : NaNs produced the value of 'y' is 24 but the log(y) gives an error message.

I am not sure what I am missing. Thanks a lot for your help.**

Comment: If `n` is not `1`, shouldn't you have a second `return <value>`?

Comment: Thanks David, I went back and added return log(y), it and it shows 24, it did not change the end result, it still returns NaN warning message. If it is just "return( y)", not return log(y), then it correctly returns the "n-1" factorial..just frustrated not sure where I am missing..thanks a lot

Comment: Not `return log(y)` but `return y`. I don't know the particular language you are using but I guess `log(blabla)` would cause the value of `blabla` to be shown in the console, and this has nothing to do with performing the factorial calculation.

Comment: For n = 2 you will have 0 (log 1), for n = 3 you will have -Inf (log 0) and for everything else you will have log(-Inf) which gives you the error. What is your aim with this function?

Comment: Thanks user2321, my outcome is log(n-1)!--log of n-1 factorial.

Comment: @Victor do you need to do this recursively? And do you need to build your own function instead of using built-in functions?

Comment: Thans Dason, Yes I will have to do this recursively as it is the requirement and it needs to be the own function. Thanks

Comment: You should remember that log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b) ...

Comment: You're getting NANs because once you get down to `log_gamma_recursive(2)`, the calculation run by your code is log(1) = 0. Since `R` evaluates `log(0)` to `-Inf`, `log_gamma_recursive(2)` will be `-Inf` (log(2 * 0)) and `log_gamma_recursive(3)` will therefore be `NaN` (`log(-Inf)`). @MrSmithGoesToWashington gives you  a good clue how to change the maths in your code.

Comment: thanks. Milan. Not sure how to  change the code. Do you have any suggestions. If I pass n=5, the code correctly evaluates n-1 factorial as 24 but log of 24 is not evaluated right..Any suggestions how to fix? thanks a lot Victor

Comment: I feel like doing your homework .. `log_gamma_recursive <- function(n) 
{
  if (n >= 1) {log_gamma_recursive(n-1)  + log(n)} else {0}
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot ---MrSmithGoesToWashington. I will try that...Thanks again..